# SQL Server: does SQL Server 2008 64 bit support DTS Runtime?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, migration, dts

I am looking online and would like to migrate my DTS Packages to SSIS using migration wizard, but when I go to convert packages it says I must Install DTS Runtime, when I look online, at MSDN, it says : When planning to install support for DTS packages, know that SQL Server 2008 does not include support for DTS in the following circumstances:

```
There is no 64-bit design-time or run-time support for DTS packages. On a 64-bit computer, DTS packages, and Integration Services packages that use the Execute DTS 2000 Package task to run DTS packages, can run only in 32-bit mode.
```

Can anyone confirm that I cannot use the dts migration wizard on a 64 bit machine in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: What it's saying is that SSIS packages can run in 64-bit mode, but if you want to "Execute DTS Task" in your SSIS package, the SSIS package must be executed in 32-bit mode, since there is no 64-bit handler for DTS task/packages. It does not relate to being able to migrate a DTS package to SSIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DTS was deprecated.  I would just go ahead and rebuild it using SSIS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440.aspx

Comment: And you can even migrate those DTS packages with a tool: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/dts-to-ssis-migration/